# Conectar Java con SQL Server 2017 en Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Estoy usando Eclipse Oxygen para desarrollar un programa en Java y quiero usar SQL Server 2017 para guardar la información. Leí en otros sitios cómo hacerlo, pero, no me funciona.

Pasos que he hecho hasta ahora:

- Descargué el [Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774).
- Lo agregué a mi proyecto en Eclipse Oxygen.
- Agregué el Driver en el Java Build Path de mi proyecto.
- Tengo mi base de datos creada usando SQL Server Management Studio
  v17.3.
- En SQL Server Network Configuration, tengo TCP/IP y Named Pipes
  activados.
- En Windows Defender Firewall, tengo el puerto 1433 abierto.

El código que tengo es:

```
public class ConexionSQL {

    // Librería de SQL
    public String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

    // Nombre de la base de datos
    public String database = "industriaCine";

    // Host
    public String hostname = "localhost";

    // Puerto predeterminado para SQL Server
    public String port = "1433";

    // Ruta de nuestra base de datos ("integratedSecurity=true" establece que usaremos la autenticación integrada de Windows)
    public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + hostname + ";databaseName=" + database + ";integratedSecurity=true";

    public Connection conectarSQL() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: conectarSQL()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

En Eclipse recibo estos errores en la consola:

> Nov 05, 2017 9:33:23 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI
>    WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no
>   sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
>   configured for integrated authentication.
>   ClientConnectionid:fe7aa3ab-3308-4602-9918-ef166b69118

Qué me falta para poder conectarme a SQL Server?.

Tengo algo mal en el código?.

Comment: ¿Qué sucede con el código que tienes? ¿Recibes algún error?

Comment: Recibo este error, SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. El driver de SQL en mi código no es el correcto?

Comment: Parece que algo no funcionó bien con la etapa de agregar el `sqljdbc42.jar` a tu proyecto. No soy usuario de Eclipse, así que no puedo ayudarte mucho con eso.  Pero el código en sí se ve bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que tu proyecto no conoce las clases que contiene la librería sqljdbc42.jar

No basta con copiar el archivo a tu proyecto, debes agregar la librería al proyecto desde el Built Path.

¿Has realizado este paso? En caso de que no, tendrías que ir a las propiedades del proyecto (Botón derecho sobre el proyecto > Properties), ir a la pestaña "Java Build Path", y en la sección "Libraries" pulsas el botón "Add JARs" y seleccionas el fichero sqlserver42.jar

Comment: Gracias, me faltaba eso también. Estaba recibiendo otro error sobre "sqljdbc_auth.dll". Investigué un poco y resulta que hay que agregar ese archivo también en "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin". Ahora todo funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Te falto quizá la librería que viene junto con el driver para JDBC para sqlserver es el *.dll que se encuentra en la carpeta (auth), tienes que ponerla en tu proyecto principal.Vienen para dos arquitecturas x86 y x64.
Luego reinicia tu servicio de SQLServer para guardar los cambios del administrador de configuración de SQLserver.